# linq returning a bidimensional Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

How to mount a query on linq to return something like this `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>`?

---

if someone have the same question here is an example answer for this.

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>
 retorno =(
                from x in  rss.Descendants("teste").Descendants()
                where  x.Descendants().Count() > 1
                select new {nome = x.Name.ToString(), valor =(
                from c in x.Descendants()
                select c).ToDictionary(c=>c.Name.ToString(),c=>c.Value.ToString())}).ToDictionary(x=>x.nome,x=>x.valor);
```

Comment: You'll have to tell us what your source data looks like before we can make a useful suggestion

Comment: Post the data you have and the result you want. The piece of code you posted isn't very helpful...

Comment: Can you show some of the Xml  content?